# Why users are not saying at least some words about unacceptable (due to be silly) questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have asked this question [How combinatorics is related to the study of emergence in the complex systems theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820884/how-combinatorics-is-related-to-the-study-of-emergence-in-the-complex-systems-th) and now it is experiencing heaving closevoting. The question is not bad and I have invested quite a effort to write it - it exploratory, it contains interesting ideas, it contains some very interesting references which are mostly unknown to the community and which Google is not inclined to reveal when one searched about automation of mathematics. And yet - the question is being close-voted. I think that those closevotes are because the question is silly. For SE scholars it may be obvious that the mathematical practice is totally different than one I have imagined in my question. Well - I am not afraid to ask silly questions. But it would be nice to receive the relevant feedback.

So - is it really so hard to give one-sentence statement about the question that is silly and totally out of the normas of the current research practices?

Comment: The close reason, given in the blue box at the top of your question, is that your question needs to be more focused.  In other words, narrow it down to something that a Q&A site (i.e. M.SE) can actually answer.  There are no comments criticizing the ideas or the statements of the question, so your supposition about the reason for the close vote appears unfounded.  As it stands, I don't see how anyone could reasonably provide an answer to your question, which appears to be an invitation to discussion.  **Focus** it, and you may get the answers you desire.

Comment: I see no one calling your question "silly", except for *you calling it silly*, @TomR.  You seem to claim, in your title that the question was closed for "being too silly", but in fact, you are the only one describing it as silly.

Comment: @postmortes I think you should turn that into an answer - your comment contains pretty much everything I would want in an answer to this meta question.

Comment: I like to think of *combinatorics* as the crazy uncle of the mathematical family.  He is related to everyone, but no one is really sure of the extent of their relationship.

Comment: @amWhy I think English is not his first language. I agree that he is the only one using the word silly, but it is being used in more than one way, so that one of us would have used a few different English words if composing his question. I wrote some articles with a Russian professor (in the US for years). I had to edit for grammar, but mostly for overuse of certain words or phrases; he used the word Laconic two or three times in the same page, that is the one I remember all these years later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A question is closed when five users with sufficient reputation vote to close that question.  When such a user votes to close a question, they must provide some reason.  There are several reasons which are built-in, or a voting user can provide a custom comment.  If the user provides a custom comment, this comment will be added below the post.  Otherwise, once the question is closed, the most common reason for closure will be included in a banner above the post.  For example, the question cited here displays the following banner:

[image]

In this case, your question was closed because the voting users felt that it was too broad, and that it should be more narrowly focused.  Additional information can be found by clicking on the various links in the banner above the post.

In the case of the question being discussed here, I sympathize with the close voters.  Your question, if I understand it correctly, is "how are combinatorics and emergence related?"  This could be the topic of a semester long class, which immediately implies that it cannot easily be answered in two or three paragraphs.  As such, it isn't a good fit for this site.  Try to narrow it down to a more specific problem.

Comment: You said that the answer could be as semester long class. So far - of what I know or what I don't know - I feel that there is no connection at all. I have tried to find at least one research paper, at least one blog post that describe such connection, but I have not found any. So - I am desperate to have any information. If you are saying that there is so much information about this, please, give at least one paper, at least one hint, at least one reference! That would be ideal answer - just any hint!

Comment: I feel that such connection should exist but I am desperate to find the initial thread of research in this domain, that is why I asked my initial question and that is why I expected at least one very, very small hint, it would be an answer and I would have accepted it. Wasn't that obvious from my question and from the state of the art? Sometimes I wonder how much my thinking differs from the SE generally.

Comment: So - I described my feelings and sentiment in previous 2 comments. Judging from them - how differently could I put my question? I feel that I made it right.

Comment: You asked for a one-sentence statement addressing the reason for closing your question, TomR. You got a paragraph from @postmortes, and three paragraphs from Xander, and instead of showing gratitude and taking their words to heart, you are fighting back. Some may question whether your question here was asked in good faith.

Comment: @TomR Like I said, getting from basic combinatorics to emergence would likely take a semester (or more).  One possible path (excuse the pun, which will become apparent in a second) is to think about how ordered, predictable behaviour emerges from the chaotic behaviour of random walks.  Random walks can be analyzed combinatorially, and give rise to Brownian paths (told ya), which are stochastic, but which have statistical regularity.  However, actually expanding this idea into an informative answer is beyond the scope of this site, and still barely addresses the original question.